# Get id element without "?"

Tags: javascript, php

I want to get the id element from the url without '?' in php
Like : 
In php get the url will be

```
http://exp.com/dir/index.php?id=123
```

So i tried to use javascript to get this

```
http://exp.com/dir/123
```

My code in javascript was

```
var url = document.URL;
var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
alert(id);
```

But when i go idon't get an alret box say the 123
It says not found because the server think that i want a directory 
Can someone help with my javascript code ?

Comment: You must the server tell how to behave when `http://exp.com/dir/123` is requested. In your case, you want `http://exp.com/dir/123` to behave as `http://exp.com/dir/index.php?id=123`. If you are using Apache, have a look at [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: It's fairly easy to retrieve those variables using PHP. However, while JavaScript can give you the page's current URL with window.location, it doesn't have automatic retrieval methods I know of to parse the end of the string like the serverside languages do. However, please be consistent about which language you're trying to do this in! Your first line says PHP. Your last line says JS.

Comment: Do you want to be able to surf to the url: `http://exp.com/dir/123`...or do you want to alert the id value once you're on that page?

Comment: @Niklas i want to be able to surf to the url: http://exp.com/dir/123

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a problem that can be solved through JavaScript.

Your server needs to serve up content for the URL you're trying to access before JavaScript can even run. You need to look into [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: Thank you but can you help more explain just more ?

Comment: There are a *ton* of questions on Stack Overflow covering the use of mod_rewrite. You need to do a little research for yourself.

Comment: Note, [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) is a module for an Apache HTTP server — bugged, 19 years old web server only. There is no word about what web server (if) uses author.

Comment: @Benio It's a reasonable assumption when talking about PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use htacces.
That way you can reshape the url for php to understand

For example:/page/id would be

```
RewriteRule   ^(.*)/([0-9]+)?$   index.php?page=$2&id=$1  [NC,L]
```